# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List< >' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList< >'

Tags: c#, linq

There are lots of possible duplicates for this post.But i tried most of thems, unfortunately my error still
happens.

> Error is : Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<Report.Business.ViewModels.InvoiceMaster>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.IList<ICSNew.Data.InvoiceHD>'`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
public IList<InvoiceHD> GetAllInvoiceMasterDetailsByInvoiceId(int InvoiceId)
{
    var dbMstDtl = ireportrepository.GetAllInvoiceMasterDetailsByInvoiceId(InvoiceId);

    var MstDtl = from mst in dbMstDtl 
                 select new Report.Business.ViewModels.InvoiceMaster 
                 {
                     ModifiedDate = mst.ModifiedDate,
                     SubTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(mst.SubTotal),
                     TotalDiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(mst.TotalDiscount),
                     VAT = Convert.ToDecimal(mst.VAT),
                     NBT = Convert.ToDecimal(mst.NBT),
                     AmtAfterDiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(mst.AmtAfterDiscount)
                 };

    return MstDtl.ToList();
}
```

In some post i saw this thing solved when they use  **return MstDtl.AsEnumerable().ToList();**

But in my case it also not working(getting errors)

Comment: have you tried `return MstDtl as IList<InvoiceHD>`

Comment: Your creating a collection of `InvoiceMaster` so your signature needs to be `public IList<InvoiceMaster> ...`

Comment: How are InvoiceMaster and InvoiceHD related?

Comment: @vallabha: That would just return `null` every time, because the result of a LINQ query like this is *never* an `IList<T>`, regardless of the `T`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming `InvoiceMaster` derives from or implements `InvoiceHD`, and that you're using C# 4 and .NET 4 or higher, you can just use generic variance:

```
return MstDtl.ToList<InvoiceHD>();
```

This uses the fact that an `IEnumerable<InvoiceMaster>` is an `IEnumerable<InvoiceHD>` because `IEnumerable<T>` is *covariant* in `T`.

Another way to solve it would be to change the declaration of `MstDtl` to use explicit typing:

```
IEnumerable<InvoiceMaster> MstDtl = ...;
```

(I'd also suggest following regular C# naming, where local variables start with a lower-case letter, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Now Error is Error 2 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Report.Business.ViewModels.InvoiceMaster>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @TechGuy: Well *does* `InvoiceMaster` derive from `InvoiceHD`? You haven't told us that.

Comment: @TechGuy: Then it should be fine. What version of C# and .NET are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the wrong type. Your method signature says that you are returning a collection of `InvoiceHD` but you are actually returning a collection of `InvoiceMaster`

You are returning the wrong type

Answer (score 2):

if InvoiceHD is a subtype of Report.Business.ViewModels.InvoiceMaster:

```
MstDtl.Cast<InvoiceHD>().ToList()
```

or if ICSNew.Data.InvoiceHD does not derive from Report.Business.ViewModels.InvoiceMaster then you can map your data manualy:

```
var MstDtl = from mst in dbMstDtl 
                 select new InvoiceHD //return InvoiceHD instead of Report.Business.ViewModels.InvoiceMaster
                 {
                     ModifiedDate = mst.ModifiedDate,
                     SubTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(mst.SubTotal),
                     TotalDiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(mst.TotalDiscount),
                     VAT = Convert.ToDecimal(mst.VAT),
                     NBT = Convert.ToDecimal(mst.NBT),
                     AmtAfterDiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(mst.AmtAfterDiscount)
                 }
```

or change a return type of your function from InvoiceHD to

```
public IList<Report.Business.ViewModels.InvoiceMaster> GetAllInvoiceMasterDetailsByInvoiceId(int InvoiceId)
```

Comment: When i use this ,then error occured Unable to cast object of type 'Report.Business.ViewModels.InvoiceMaster' to type 'ICSNew.Data.InvoiceHD'.