# IList<IList<int>> doesn't accept List<List<int>>?

Tags: c#, generics

List implements IList so I expect IList will accept a List object
but why IList> doesn't accept List>?

```
static IList<int> List_1()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 1,2,3,3,4,5};

        return list;
    }

    static IList<IList<int>> List_2()
    {
        List<List<int>> parent = new List<List<int>>();
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 };
        parent.Add(list);

        return parent; //compiler error CS0266
    }
```

Comment: Do you understand why `List<object>` doesn't accept `List<string>`?

Comment: return (IList<IList<int>>)parent;

Comment: @jdweng: That won't work, you'll get a runtime exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I cast from a List<MyClass> to List<object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881677/why-cant-i-cast-from-a-listmyclass-to-listobject)

Comment: @SᴇM It is not about casting one type to an object type it is about IList and List.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501312/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-collections-generic-list-to-system-c

Comment: @vsarunov You know right, that compiler gives an error, because it cannot cast from `List<List<int>>` to `IList<IList<int>>`?

Comment: @SᴇM So does that have to do with casting List<MyClass> to List<object> ? If I had this problem It would be simple a linq statement or using just "as" or "is" and checking if you can cast it. It is specifically IList and List.

Comment: @vsarunov Yes it does, cause `MyClass` derived from `object`, as `List<T>` derived from `IList<T>`. So if you have for example method which returns `List<object>`, you cannot return `List<MyClass>` without casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of

`List<T>` implements `IList<T>` but

`List<List<T>>` does not implement `IList<IList<int>>`

That's why your first method works as intended and second not.

Just change your declaration of the list in the second method to

```
List<IList<int>> parent = new List<IList<int>>();
```

And this is the case of covariance and contravariance.

*Generic type parameters support covariance and contravariance but you need to define in that way*

By [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

> Covariance and contravariance are terms that refer to the ability to use a more derived type (more specific) or a less derived type (less specific) than originally specified. Generic type parameters support covariance and contravariance to provide greater flexibility in assigning and using generic types

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this works. Your client code is:

```
var result = List_2();
```

Since the contract allows adding to the result anything that's `IList<int>`, you could possibly have

```
public class MyCustomIList : IList<int>
{
    ...
}
```

and then

```
var result = List_2();
result.Add( new MyCustomIList() );
```

But that's wrong!

Your `result` is a list of `List<int>`, you should not be allowed to add anything other than `List<int>` or its derivatives there. However, you were able to add `MyCustomIList` which is **not related** to the `List<int>`.

If you need a broad picture of the issue, read more on [covariance and contravariance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance/).

The fundamental issue in this particular example comes from the `Add` operation. If you don't need it, the `IEnumerable` will do

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> List_2()
{
    List<List<int>> parent = new List<List<int>>();
    List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 };
    parent.Add(list);

    return parent; // no error, this works
}
```

This has been [covered already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832094/covariance-and-ilist).

Answer (score 0):

> Why then does List implement IList?
>
> It is a bit odd, since List for any type other than object does not
>   fulfill the full contract of IList. It's probably to make it easier on
>   people who are updating old C# 1.0 code to use generics; those people
>   were probably already ensuring that only the right types got into
>   their lists. And most of the time when you're passing an IList around,
>   it is so the callee can get by-index access to the list, not so that
>   it can add new items of arbitrary type.

I would suggeste return IEnumerable instead of IList, will simplify your life, since List Fully implements it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to return exactly `IList<IList<int>>`, but one way of doing that is to use [`Cast<T>()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8):

```
static IList<IList<int>> List_2()
{
    List<List<int>> parent = new List<List<int>>();
    List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 };
    parent.Add(list);

    return parent.Cast<IList<int>>().ToList();
}
```

Or [`ConvertAll()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.convertall?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.List%601.ConvertAll%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8):

```
return parent.ConvertAll(x => (IList<int>)x);
```

Both methods will run over all elemets, and cast/convert them to a given type, so I think it would be better to return `IList<List<int>>` instead (if that's possible).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your method `return type`. Modify your method signature to return to `IList<List<int>>` rather than returning `IList<IList<int>>`

```
static IList<List<int>> List_2()
    {
        List<List<int>> parent = new List<List<int>>();
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 };
        parent.Add(list);

        return parent; //no compiler error
    }
```

Now it will work fine as your method now returns an `IList` of `List<int>`